# VBA - EXCEL Remove columns except specified range

Tags: vba, excel

I was looking for answers however I can't find one so specific.

I am trying to write macro which will be easy to use for people without any programming knowledge.

So we use pricing template where you can see prices for many different countries. I want to create a macro which will copy whole tab and remove unwanted columns depends from for which country it is creating file. (Needed to preserve formulas, I still want to have all the calculation not values).

So first few columns will stay since they are common for all countries, and then all the columns except selected range should be deleted. Ranges are specified in separate tab and will be stored in array.

Example:
Belgium
First Column: CJ
Last Column: CQ

So let's say in first loop first column and last column values are stored, and I want macro remove columns from H to CI and then from CR to HF.

However in next loop first and last will change so delete ranges have to recalculate.

I tried with formulas ASC and CHR but it doesn't work with two letters codes.

Comment: Is there a unique header for each column?

Comment: Almost...  Yes there is unique header but in 3rd row

Comment: If the unique header can be used to identify the columns you want to keep you can simply loop through the columns from H to the end of your data and delete the ones that do not fit the pattern.

Comment: If you're going to loop, you're better off working from the end and moving forward, else all of your columns will be shifted forward @ each deletion.

Comment: Iterate backwards (e.g., `For LoopControl = 214 To 1 Step -1: If LoopControl >96 Or (LoopControl <= {Last column in next block to be deleted} And LoopControl > {First column in that same block}) Or ... Then ActiveSheet.Columns(LoopControl).Delete: Next LoopControl`). If speed is desired, again starting with last set of columns, `ActiveSheet.Columns(96).Resize(, 118).Delete`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already know the ranges you want to use, a subroutine like this could remove a range of columns, minus an exception range.

I'm just looping through the columns and checking for an intersection. If there is no intersection between the column being tested and the exception range, we add it to the list of columns to be deleted.

```vb
Public Sub RemoveColumnsExcept(removeRange As Range, exceptRange As Range)
  Dim deletionRange As Range
  Dim columnRange As Range

  For Each columnRange In removeRange.Columns
    If Intersect(columnRange, exceptRange) Is Nothing Then
      If deletionRange Is Nothing Then
        Set deletionRange = columnRange
      Else
        Set deletionRange = Union(deletionRange, columnRange)
      End If
    End If
  Next columnRange

  If Not deletionRange Is Nothing Then
    deletionRange.Delete xlShiftToLeft
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub Test()
  RemoveColumnsExcept Sheet1.[B:J], Sheet1.[G:I]
End Sub
```

You could use named ranges to keep track of the columns you want deleted. That or column headers and a loop looking for some value like country code in a specific row.